# Select specific rows from a groupby DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in the following format:

```
56.00 101.85 52.40 101.85 56.000000 101.850000 1
56.00 100.74 50.60 100.74 56.000000 100.740000 2
56.00 100.74 52.10 100.74 56.000000 100.740000 3
56.00 102.96 52.40 102.96 56.000000 102.960000 4
56.00 100.74 55.40 100.74 56.000000 100.740000 5
56.00 103.70 54.80 103.70 56.000000 103.700000 6
56.00 101.85 53.00 101.85 56.000000 101.850000 7
56.00 102.22 52.10 102.22 56.000000 102.220000 8
56.00 101.11 55.40 101.11 56.000000 101.110000 9
56.00 101.11 54.80 101.11 56.000000 101.110000 10
56.00 101.85 52.40 101.85 56.000000 101.850000 1
56.00 100.74 50.60 100.74 56.000000 100.740000 2
........
```

What I need are the data for a specific `id` (last column). 
With `numpy` I used to do:

```
d=loatxt('filename')
wanted = d[ d[:,6]==id ]
```

Now I' m learning Pandas and found out, that `pandas.read_csv()` is *really* faster that `loadtxt()`.

So logically I was wondering if there is a possibility to do he same filtering with pandas (maybe it is even faster).

My first thought was trying `groupby` as follows:

```
p=pd.read_csv('filename', sep= ' ', header=None, names=['a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'c', 'd', 'id'])

d = p.groupby(['id'])
#[ i, g in p.groupby(['id']) if i ==1] # syntax error, why?
```

The question is: Is there a relatively easy way to do the selection from `p` of the rows of let's say `id==1`?

**EDIT**

Trying the proposed solution:

```
%timeit t_1 = n[ n[:,6]==1 ][:,2:4]
10 loops, best of 3: 60.8 ms per loop

%timeit t_2 = p[ p['id'] == 1 ][['x', 'y']]
10 loops, best of 3: 70.9 ms per loop
```

It seems that `numpy` is here a bit faster that `Pandas`

That means the fastest way to work in this case is:
1) First read the data with Pandas `read_csv`
2) Convert the data to `numpy.array`
3) and than the work.

Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: First, I think the difference is really small. So the important question is: what is the easiest to work with for you and for your application: numpy or pandas? You can certainly read the data with pandas and then further work with a numpy array, but if you like to work with named columns, or have heterogeneous data, I think it can really benefit to keep you data in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Something else, the chained indexing is not really advised, you can also do: ``p.loc[p['id']==1, ['x', 'y']]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do just the same as you did with numpy, just now refering to the column by its name:

```
wanted = d[d['id'] == id]
```

Comment: That was really obvious! :-) Was so much fixed on the groupby idea. Anyway, that that not seem to be fast that the numpy version